# Что делать если из-за js кода зависает сайт

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Использую этот код чтобы сделать анимированный фон для блока
https://codepen.io/laurentschoonbrodt/pen/NqdPpy
Но из-за него очень тормозит сайт, можно его чем-то заменить чтобы сайт так не тормозил

```
var refreshDuration = 10000;
var refreshTimeout;
var numPointsX;
var numPointsY;
var unitWidth;
var unitHeight;
var points;

function onLoad()
{
var svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
svg.setAttribute('width',window.innerWidth);
svg.setAttribute('height',window.innerHeight);
document.querySelector('#bg').appendChild(svg);

var unitSize = (window.innerWidth+window.innerHeight)/20;
numPointsX = Math.ceil(window.innerWidth/unitSize)+1;
numPointsY = Math.ceil(window.innerHeight/unitSize)+17;
unitWidth = Math.ceil(window.innerWidth/(numPointsX-1));
unitHeight = Math.ceil(window.innerHeight/(numPointsY-17));

points = [];

for(var y = 0; y < numPointsY; y++) {
    for(var x = 0; x < numPointsX; x++) {
        points.push({x:unitWidth*x, y:unitHeight*y, originX:unitWidth*x, 
originY:unitHeight*y});
    }
}

randomize();

for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    if(points[i].originX != unitWidth*(numPointsX-1) && points[i].originY != 
unitHeight*(numPointsY-1)) {
        var topLeftX = points[i].x;
        var topLeftY = points[i].y;
        var topRightX = points[i+1].x;
        var topRightY = points[i+1].y;
        var bottomLeftX = points[i+numPointsX].x;
        var bottomLeftY = points[i+numPointsX].y;
        var bottomRightX = points[i+numPointsX+1].x;
        var bottomRightY = points[i+numPointsX+1].y;

        var rando = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);

        for(var n = 0; n < 2; n++) {
            var polygon = document.createElementNS(svg.namespaceURI, 
'polygon');

            if(rando==0) {
                if(n==0) {
                    polygon.point1 = i;
                    polygon.point2 = i+numPointsX;
                    polygon.point3 = i+numPointsX+1;
                    polygon.setAttribute('points',topLeftX+','+topLeftY+' 
'+bottomLeftX+','+bottomLeftY+' '+bottomRightX+','+bottomRightY);
                } else if(n==1) {
                    polygon.point1 = i;
                    polygon.point2 = i+1;
                    polygon.point3 = i+numPointsX+1;
                    polygon.setAttribute('points',topLeftX+','+topLeftY+' 
'+topRightX+','+topRightY+' '+bottomRightX+','+bottomRightY);
                }
            } else if(rando==1) {
                if(n==0) {
                    polygon.point1 = i;
                    polygon.point2 = i+numPointsX;
                    polygon.point3 = i+1;
                    polygon.setAttribute('points',topLeftX+','+topLeftY+' 
'+bottomLeftX+','+bottomLeftY+' '+topRightX+','+topRightY);
                } else if(n==1) {
                    polygon.point1 = i+numPointsX;
                    polygon.point2 = i+1;
                    polygon.point3 = i+numPointsX+1;

polygon.setAttribute('points',bottomLeftX+','+bottomLeftY+' 
'+topRightX+','+topRightY+' '+bottomRightX+','+bottomRightY);
                }
            }
            polygon.setAttribute('fill','rgba(255, 165, 0,'+
(Math.random()/1)+')');
            polygon.setAttribute('stroke','rgba(250,250,250,'+
(Math.random()/1)+')');
            var animate = 
document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','animate');
            animate.setAttribute('fill','freeze');
            animate.setAttribute('attributeName','points');
            animate.setAttribute('dur',refreshDuration+'ms');
            animate.setAttribute('calcMode','linear');
            polygon.appendChild(animate);
            svg.appendChild(polygon);
        }
    }
}
var ktmp;
var k;
setInterval(function(){
  var j=document.querySelector('#bg svg').childNodes.length;
  ktmp=k;
  k=parseInt(j*Math.random());
  var polygon0 = document.querySelector('#bg svg').childNodes[ktmp];
  var polygon1 = document.querySelector('#bg svg').childNodes[k];
  var tmp=polygon1.getAttribute('fill');
  polygon0.setAttribute('fill',tmp);
  polygon1.setAttribute('fill','rgba(255,255,255,.7)');
}
,500);
 refresh();
}

function randomize() {
for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    if(points[i].originX != 0 && points[i].originX != unitWidth*(numPointsX-
1)) {
        points[i].x = points[i].originX + Math.random()*unitWidth-
unitWidth/2;
    }
    if(points[i].originY != 0 && points[i].originY != unitHeight*
(numPointsY-1)) {
        points[i].y = points[i].originY + Math.random()*unitHeight-
unitHeight/2;
    }
}
}

function refresh() {
randomize();
for(var i = 0; i < document.querySelector('#bg svg').childNodes.length; i++) 
{
    var polygon = document.querySelector('#bg svg').childNodes[i];
    var animate = polygon.childNodes[0];
    if(animate.getAttribute('to')) {
        animate.setAttribute('from',animate.getAttribute('to'));
    }
    animate.setAttribute('to',points[polygon.point1].x+',
'+points[polygon.point1].y+' 
'+points[polygon.point2].x+','+points[polygon.point2].y+' 
'+points[polygon.point3].x+','+points[polygon.point3].y);
    animate.beginElement();
}
refreshTimeout = setTimeout(function() {refresh();}, refreshDuration);
}

function onResize() {
document.querySelector('#bg svg').remove();
clearTimeout(refreshTimeout);
onLoad();
}

window.onload = onLoad;
window.onresize = onResize;
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/ 
Видел на многих сайтах

Comment: а как сделать этот фон сразу в двух блоках на сайте, а то вставляю, но работает лишь в одном блоке